# Firebase hosting redirect http to https in custom domain

Tags: http, redirect, https, firebase-hosting

I hosted a website in firebase hosting and connected a custom domain, the domain is connected properly as you can see in the screenshot.
[firebase hosting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMUnd.png)

The problem is if someone for the **first time** in their browsing session writes `http://plucreo.com` it does not get redirect to `https://plucreo.com` and the connection gets timed out. This does not happen with the default domain `http://plucreo.web.app` it redirects to `https://` one correctly.

But, if you manually type `https://plucreo.com` in address bar, for the current browsing session `http://plucreo.com` starts correctly redirecting to `https://` one.

How to fix this redirecting issue?

Comment: `http://plucreo.com` is redirecting fine for me. Maybe it was just a temporary issue.

Comment: @abraham is this problem region-wise? I am still facing the same issue here.

Comment: It could be, there might also be some issue with your machine. Try other browsers and try curl in a terminal so see if you get different results.

Comment: @abraham thanks for your reply. I think I found the issue when I was connected to my mobile data there was no issue with redirection but when I'm connected to my broadband I'm facing the same issue. I don't know why this is happening, I need to dig into this more.